# Access to a current selector jQuery selector before

Tags: jquery

I do not speak much English, sorry for any grammar or spelling errors.
I have a piece of code like this in HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<a href="#">
    <img class="post_user" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/" />
</a>
```

I want the images within each class "box" to display the image that is loaded in my code 
I wrote it for load detection photo:

```
$('.box img.imgcheck').on('load', function () {
 //code
});
```

Now you're part of the "code" what I write or what I can pick up the "box" to access the images are loaded?

This is an image that may help explain what I am attempting to do: http://uc.mihanu.ir/uploads/14052766771.png

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is written in Persian

Comment: Must be written in English?
Someone who doesn't speak English, what is the solution?

Comment: Sorry. Sites in Iran are much higher than this site to answer questions. Goodbye forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want.
Would this work ?

`$('.box img.imgcheck').on('load', function () {
    $(this).fadeIn()
});`

Comment: Thanks for your answer-But this was not the correct answer to my question.